# pip3 cannot install .whl files on raspberry pi: File is not a zip file

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

can anyone help me please
i am trying to install tensorflow 2.3.0 on my raspberry pi 3 (Buster)
i have python 3.7.3 and pip 20.3.3
when i try to install my .whl file i get the following:

```
~ $ sudo -H pip3 install tensorflow-2.3.0-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Processing ./tensorflow-2.3.0-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 338, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 283, in prepare_linked_requirement
    progress_bar=self.progress_bar
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 823, in unpack_url
    unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 728, in unpack_file_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 600, in unpack_file
    flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 485, in unzip_file
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfp, allowZip64=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 1222, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 1289, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

I have tried to delete and then reinstall the packages still nothing happened

Comment: Where did you get the file from? Can you give a link to it?

Comment: Try to download tensorflow2.3.0 from [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.3.0/#files).

Comment: thank you guys. it turns out the file was not installed properly due to the slow internet connection. it is working now. thanks for your trouble!

Comment: You mean the file was corrupt and not downloaded correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the wheel file was not downloaded and saved properly due to the slow internet connection. It is working now. If you want to know whether it was downloaded and saved properly or not, change the extension to .zip and open it. If it doesn't open this means that your wheel file is corrupted.

Comment: You can also execute e.g. `unzip -l tensorflow-2.3.0-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl` directly, no need to rename the file just to check its consistency.